# MySQL damaged system tables

Tags: mysql, event-scheduler

I ran a query that hung my mysql dameon pretty bad. Still not sure what thats about. 
When I tried to restart MySQL, I was getting errors that the service could not be stopped, so I killed the process (probably not a good idea in hindsight). When I tried to restart the MySQL service I get:

```
$ ERROR 1577 (HY000) at line 1: Cannot proceed because system tables used by Event Scheduler were found damaged at server start
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to your MySQL database directory (usually /var/lib/mysql/mysql), and then do a [myisamchk](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisamchk.html) to repair all the tables, then try again. It is likely that more than 1 tables were damaged in this case, and you want to fix them all. If you really cannot, you would have to copy it from a backup or an equivalent setup. Please don't say you have no backups :-)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up running $ mysqlcheck --auto-repair --all-databases --password

Comment: @TechplexEngineer Your solution works perfectly after I tried many hours to search solution on Google.